# RibbonComboBox's SelectedValue property issue

Tags: wpf, ribbon-control

I just started working in a WPF project using a Ribbon Bar, but I am stuck with the RibbonComboBox.

I need to add 3 items, so what I have done so far is:

```
<RibbonComboBox Name="phaseComboBox">
                    <RibbonGallery>
                        <RibbonGalleryCategory>
                            <RibbonGalleryItem>
                                Phase 1
                            </rb:RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <RibbonGalleryItem>
                                Phase 2
                            </RibbonGalleryItem>
                            <RibbonGalleryItem>
                                Phase 3
                            </RibbonGalleryItem>
                        </RibbonGalleryCategory>
                    <RibbonGallery>
</RibbonComboBox>
```

But I need the first element to get selected at first, so, I set the `RibbonGalleryCategory`'s `SelectedValue` property to `Phase 1`, but it never gets selected.

What am I doing wrong? It may be a very easy question, but it is the first time I develop a Ribbon Bar.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the focus? Is it on the RibbonComboBox?

Comment: No, my focus is in another control

Comment: Then are you sure it is not selected. It might be selected but just not focused and you cant tell. I had that problem on a list box, which the selected item was a very light shade of grey because the list box was not focused. Once I set the focus on the list box and then selected the item, it "looked" selected.

Comment: Yes, Im sure, i need to select manually the element in order to get it selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem:

I just have to set the `IsSelected` property to `True` in the element:

```
<RibbonGalleryItem Content="Phase 1" IsSelected="True" />
```